# Updating an application from titanium sdk 3.4.0.GA to 9.2.0.GA making my fonts looks very very small

Tags: titanium, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

Default uint is set to dp.

```
<property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">dp</property>
```

All the font size is set with dp unit in tss files. Like below

```
 font: {
        fontSize: '16dp'    
    }
```

I manually updating all style files front size from '10dp' to '17sp' (like that) increased my font little bit but all the popup and other font is still very very small to see.

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="false"/>
```

I have tried toggling it but didn't work.

I am getting a warning like below , I dont know if it has something to do with my issue. I don't know how to fix the warning.

```
[WARN]  2DMatrix: (main) [483,59911] Ti.UI.2DMatrix DEPRECATED in 8.0.0, in favor of Ti.UI.Matrix2D
```

Answer (score 1):

- remove the anyDensity part. It is true by default and should be like this
- you don't need `dp` or `sp` when you set a fontSize. Just set it to `16` (integer) without any ending
- search for `create2DMatrix` and change it to `createMatrix2D`. But that is just a deprecation warning (still update it now) but shouldn't be responsible for the fonts

If some fonts are still small it would be interesting to know where they are (e.g. you've said popup. A system popup?) or if you apply any other things like scaling or animations to them. Do you use a global theme? Just labels or Textfields?

Try setting a default value for all labels etc in app.tss

```
"Label" : {
    color: "#000",
    font: {
        fontSize: 16
    }
}

"TextField" : {
    color: "#000",
    font: {
        fontSize: 16
    }
}
```

And check the app on iOS.

Comment: All the alert dialog font is still small. I did all you said, making 16 to 26 (like that) make it's normal looking. There is no global theme, just Label, and textfield @miga

Comment: Texts are still small in higher API devices. @miga

Comment: there is no option to set an alertdialog font size besides a theme. Could you try a new app and add a dialog there to see if that is different? Or do you use a androidView in there? It is very hard to say without seeing any code. 16 should be a normal text size. Which device are you testing on?

Comment: Thanks, @miga creating a new application and copying all nessary code to there solved my issues. Including the alertdiaog Issue.